# wow.js not working with mCustomScrollbar

Tags: mcustomscrollbar, wow.js

I have applied mCustomScrollbar to the body of my page which has wow.js

I am forced to apply a height: 100% to the body of my my page and this stops wow working

Is there any way around this?